# HTML: Float:left and Relative Position

Tags: html, css

When I use a div block with float:left and another with relative position, the second block behaves unexpectedly - the text goes beyond the box and its background color. What is happening here?

https://jsbin.com/merehowoxa/1/edit?html,output

```
        #first-section{

            color:black;
            background-color:pink;
            width:100px;
            float:left;

        }

        #second-section{

            color:purple;
            background-color:yellow;
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            position:relative;
            left:500px;
            top:200px;

        }
```

Comment: I don't get why the "#second-section" is relative ??

Comment: Why cant be like this? https://jsbin.com/mitozamoja/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you use Float: left, It needs to be cleared.

Add this between both your div's

```
 <div id="first-section">

        <p>Text1</p>
        <p>Text2</p>

  </div>

  <div style="clear:both">

  <div id="second-section">
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I was just playing around mixing these features together and was wondering why the output appeared the way it did. Could you maybe explain why this happens? The output is fine with float:right

Comment: Well, applying Float to any element refers that the next immediate element will sit beside it. Unless you explicitly state (using clear:both) that the next element should not reside beside the current element.

Comment: Its because the last element (#second-section) was forced to float beside the #first-section, the content was moving out of its parent.

Comment: You can mark the answer correct if it really helped you resolved your primary problem